# Question about using declaration with virtual inheritence

Tags: c++

I'm reading about the [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration), in the section of `Inheriting constructors`, there is following code:

```cpp
struct V
{
    V() = default;
    V(int);
};
 
struct Q { Q() = default; };
 
struct A : virtual V, Q
{
    using V::V;
    A() = delete;
};
 
int bar() { return 42; }
 
struct B : A
{
    B() : A(bar()) {} // OK
};
 
struct C : B {};
 
int main()
{
    C c; // “bar” is not invoked, because the V subobject
         // is not initialized as part of B
         // (the V subobject is initialized as part of C,
         //  because “c” is the most derived object)
}
```

Accorging to the comment, the `bar()` won't be called for class `V` is a part of class `C` for class `C` is the most derived object. After removing the definition of `C`, the code seems like:

```cpp
struct V
{
    V() = default;
    V(int);
};
 
struct Q { Q() = default; };
 
struct A : virtual V, Q
{
    using V::V;
    A() = delete;
};
 
int bar() { return 42; }
 
struct B : A
{
    B() : A(bar()) {} // OK
};
 
int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

Class `B` is the most derived object and the constructor of `A(int)` is `V(int)` which is the constructor of the virtual base class, why `bar()` is still not called?

Comment: "After removing the definition of C..." please show the code you refer to rather than describing what we need to change on the code.

Comment: actually I really dont understand what I should modify on the code to "remove the definition of C" because then also the line in `main` has to be removed and nothing gets called at all

Comment: its also not clear how you notice whether `bar` is called or not. By using a debugger?

Comment: Because A(int) has no definition, or you can add some output in `bar()` instead.

Comment: after removing the definition you do not call `foo`. Sorry for nitpicking, but details do matter. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: Okay, updated, the example code is from cppreference@463035818_is_not_an_ai

Comment: Note that compilers differ in their interpretation of the standard. With g++, `bar()` is not called, but with clang and msvc, it is. It is best not to use such convoluted language features.

Comment: Comment about your [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388112/620615).

Answer (score 3):

Read what is stated before that example:

> If the Base base class subobject is not to be initialized as part of the Derived object (i.e., Base is a virtual base class of Derived, and the Derived object is not the most derived object), the invocation of the inherited constructor, including the evaluation of any arguments, is omitted:

First consider the original example. `C` is constructed. It inherits from `B`. `C`s subobject `B` is constructed, and `B`s constructor is `B() : A(bar()) {}`. One would expect that `A(bar())` is executed.

However, now the above applies: `A` inherits the constructor from `V`, the "Base". Further, `V` is a virtual base class of `A`. And the `A`, the "Derived", object is not the most derived object (we are constructing a `C`). Hence, the evaluation of `A(bar())` is ommitted.

In your modified example it is almost the same. You are constructing a `B`. `B`s constructor is `B() : A(bar()) {}`. One would expect that `A(bar())` is executed.
However, `A` inherits the constructor from `V`. `V` is a virtual base of `A`. And the `A` object is not the most derived object (we are constructing a `B`). Hence, the evaluation of `A(bar())` is ommitted.

You'd get the an error if you try to create an `A`:

```
 A a(42);
```

Because here `A` is the most derived object. Hence, `V(int)` is called, but there is not definition for `V(int)`.

Comment: Here `using declaration` generates a new ctor instead of importing the ctor of Base class?

Comment: I know the ctor of Virtual Base class should be called from the most derived object, it seems I misunderstood ctor inheritence mechanism.

Comment: @rodman10 the `using` declares that `A` inherits the constructors from `V`.

Comment: @rodman10 btw dont ask me why it works this way. I still find it puzzling too. I just went trough what cppreference explains and applied it to your modified example